# Does iOS have a built-in RSS reader?

Tags: ios, rss

Do any iOS versions come with a built-in RSS reader?

Comment: No, it haven't. The closest feature is Safari's Reading List. Have a look in this link [http://www.imore.com/how-use-safaris-reading-list-your-iphone-ipad-and-mac](http://www.imore.com/how-use-safaris-reading-list-your-iphone-ipad-and-mac)

Comment: @jherran, can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of... you can go into Safari, choose a website, then click the bookmark icon, select the **@** tab, click Subscriptions and then click Add Current Site.

Otherwise Reeder for IOS is a great RSS reader. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder-2/id697846300?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know which versions of iOS this comes with?

Comment: This comes with iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Reading List** on Safari. It's syncs automatically between all your iDevices. Reading List feature has been available on iOS since the launch of *iOS 7*. Some apps like TweetBot allow you to directly send links to the Reading List which you can catch up later.